# Cannot establish etcd cluster with SSL/TLS

Tags: etcd

I'm trying to run an etcd cluster of 3 machines (10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3) with SSL/TLS both for client and transport security, but I'm still getting into trouble, it seems like the cluster isn't able to elect its leader - raft falls into cycle. Am I doing something wrong? All machines uses etcd 2.0.5

## server1

```
etcd -name eu1 -data-dir eu1 \
  -ca-file=/root/etcd-ca/ca.crt -cert-file=/root/etcd-ca/server1.crt -key-file=/root/etcd-ca/server1.key \
  -peer-ca-file=/root/etcd-ca/ca.crt -peer-cert-file=/root/etcd-ca/server1.crt -peer-key-file=/root/etcd-ca/server1.key \
  -initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://10.0.0.1:2380 -listen-peer-urls=https://10.0.0.1:2380 \
  -discovery https://discovery.etcd.io/7855c14b6cd05060974839f3833ea932
```

## server2

```
etcd -name eu2 -data-dir eu2 \
  -ca-file=/root/etcd-ca/ca.crt -cert-file=/root/etcd-ca/server2.crt -key-file=/root/etcd-ca/server2.key \
  -peer-ca-file=/root/etcd-ca/ca.crt -peer-cert-file=/root/etcd-ca/server2.crt -peer-key-file=/root/etcd-ca/server2.key \
  -initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://10.0.0.2:2380 -listen-peer-urls=https://10.0.0.2:2380 \
  -discovery https://discovery.etcd.io/7855c14b6cd05060974839f3833ea932
```

## server3

```
etcd -name player -data-dir player \
  -ca-file=/root/etcd-ca/ca.crt -cert-file=/root/etcd-ca/server3.crt -key-file=/root/etcd-ca/server3.key \
  -peer-ca-file=/root/etcd-ca/ca.crt -peer-cert-file=/root/etcd-ca/server3.crt -peer-key-file=/root/etcd-ca/server3.key \
  -initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://10.0.0.3:2380 -listen-peer-urls=https://10.0.0.3:2380 \
  -discovery https://discovery.etcd.io/7855c14b6cd05060974839f3833ea932
```

Log file with outputs: http://pastebin.com/JBitRT1e

Thanks for any kind of help!
J.

Comment: Total shot in the dark, did you try absolute data-dirs? e.g. `/path/to/eu1` `/path/to/eu2`. Did you try again with a later version of etcd?

Comment: @josef-zamrzla Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @jmreicha yes, I've reported an issue: https://github.com/coreos/etcd/issues/2539